# IE9 with FireBug

Tags: internet-explorer-9, firebug

I am having a hard time getting IE9 to work with FireBug. I looked at a number of resources online but couldn't get it to work.

Can somebody provide a step by step guide on how to get FireBug working on IE9.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can use Firebug with IE. You need firebug lite, I think: http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the IE developer toolbar for use with IE9: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359, or firebug lite: http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite.

Answer (score 1):

Even better, if you are trying to debug a jsp or html page just stick this tag in the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>
```